Chrome-sandbox error in Arduino IDE 2.3 in Ubuntu 24.04
I'm trying to setup an installation of the IDE 2.3 in a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (beta) environment, and am facing an issue I'm unable to resolve. The IDE gets to the GUI for accepting terms and conditions, and just crashes if I try to proceed.
What I tried from the internet
The App Image complains about Chrome Sandbox. Someone has had this issue in the past, but in their case, they got a path for chrome-sandbox in /home/username/... so it was always the same, and they could chown it. I'm getting a random path in /tmp and it always vanishes after the App Image crashes.
Source: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/linux-install-issues/880034/4
CLI output
username@username-e14:/opt$ ./arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit.AppImage 
[14059:0413/233905.813890:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /tmp/.mount_arduinGsNYxm/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
username@username-e14:/opt$ ll
total 185608
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root              4096 Apr 13 23:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root  root              4096 Apr 12 10:14 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 username username  190013338 Apr 13 23:16 arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit.AppImage*
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root              4096 Apr 12 20:18 arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.Rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root              4096 Apr 12 11:07 google/
drwx------  2 root  root             16384 Apr 12 10:15 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  root              4096 Apr 12 21:10 .pio-env/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root              4096 Apr 12 20:21 STMicroelectronics/

I've tried these ownership combinations for the App Image, and all three give the same issue:
$ sudo chown username:username arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit.AppImage
$ sudo chown root:username arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit.AppImage
$ sudo chown root:root arduino-ide_2.3.2_Linux_64bit.AppImage

How do I proceed?

You can run Arduino IDE by adding --no-sandbox in the command line when starting it.
This is a workaround for a real problem with Ubuntu Noble 24.04 beta. Also other appimage files, like the one for Cider, have the same issue and solution.

Yeah, that does work... But I'm not comfortable overriding what seems to be a security feature. Also, the IDE just isn't supposed to need that flag, right? Let's wait for Canonical and OSS devs to fix it, thanks!

You can disable the new restriction in Ubuntu 24.04 for all applications using sanboxes (all those using chromium internally, AppImage apps, etc.) by adding kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0 to /etc/sysctl.conf (or a new file in /etc/sysctl.d/). Or you can create an AppArmor profile to disable the restriction to only the Arduino IDE (for examples, check any profile defined in /etc/apparmor.d/ that uses the "userns" override).

Adding this line in /etc/sysctl.conf indeed solves the issue. The --no-sandox is no longer needed. But is this a safe adaptation? Or only a temporary fix until a better solution becomes available?

@BertRAMAerts, using the sysctl change returns Ubuntu to the behavior of previous Ubuntu versions. I suggest better to configure AppArmor to except only the Arduino IDE. Check the following github report: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/2429

I miss a proper solution, which does not involve bypassing or disabling new or improved security features. (AppArmor is not exactly new, but gets improved)
